# Issue accessing LRU disk cache accross activites

Tags: android, android-listview, android-image

I am using [Jake Wharton's LRU disk cache](https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache) to store and retrive bitmaps that are displayed in a ListView. This works fine so long as I store and access bitmaps from within the same activity. However, if I try to access the cach from other activities within the app (i.e. so I don't have to downlaod the same image twice) I get a NullPointerException. Am I missing something here? This isn't a memory cache where the files could/would be removed. Shouldn't the disk cache be accessable from all the activites within the app, so long as I point them to the right directory within the internal storage?

```
01-14 22:53:44.465: E/AndroidRuntime(10720): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 22:53:44.465: E/AndroidRuntime(10720): at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:181)
01-14 22:53:44.465: E/AndroidRuntime(10720): at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:94)
01-14 22:53:44.465: E/AndroidRuntime(10720): at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:290)
01-14 22:53:44.465: E/AndroidRuntime(10720): at com.example.echofriendly.DiskLruCache.validateKey(DiskLruCache.java:629)
01-14 22:53:44.465: E/AndroidRuntime(10720): at com.example.echofriendly.DiskLruCache.get(DiskLruCache.java:375)
01-14 22:53:44.465: E/AndroidRuntime(10720): at com.example.echofriendly.DiskLruImageCache.containsKey(DiskLruImageCache.java:145)
01-14 22:53:44.465: E/AndroidRuntime(10720): at com.example.echofriendly.ChatroomFragment.getMessages(ChatroomFragment.java:309)
01-14 22:53:44.465: E/AndroidRuntime(10720): at com.example.echofriendly.ChatroomFragment.access$3(ChatroomFragment.java:284)
01-14 22:53:44.465: E/AndroidRuntime(10720): at com.example.echofriendly.ChatroomFragment$2.run(ChatroomFragment.java:94)
01-14 22:53:44.465: E/AndroidRuntime(10720): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Comment: Seems like it should work. Can you post the stack trace for the NPE?

Comment: I will post the stack trace when I get home after work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't the disk cache be accessable from all the activites within the app, so long as I point them to the right directory within the internal storage?

Sounds like you are instantiating the cache in every Activity where you need it. I don't think that is a good idea. Since Jake's LruCache uses a journal different instances that work on the same directory could in my opinion easily distract each other.

My suggestion is that you introduce some kind of singleton either as a layer between the activities and the cache or to just store the reference to exactly one cache instance for the whole application.

Furthermore I would suggest that you use some kind of two-level cache, e.g. a memcache combined with a diskcache (this is what I do in my app). So you can first check the memcache and get the image really fast if it was cached there. (can be synchronous) If it is not there you ask the diskcache. (should be asynchronous) And as last call you would download it. (also asynchronous)

Comment: Your right in that I am instantiating the cache in each activity as I need it. I am treating it almost the same way you would SharedPreferences when you read/write to it from differnt activities. How would I go about using a single reference to the cache as you suggest?

Comment: Introduce a custom `Application` class where you store the cache as `public static DiskLruCache diskCache`. This field could be instantiated either directly there. Or if you want more control over parameters use your first activity and instantiate the cache with `new` when the stored instance is `null`. Every Activity can then use `MyApplication.diskCache` when the cache is needed.

Comment: After your edit with the StackTrace it looks like you are using `null` as a key.

Comment: I'll double check the logic. I only read/write to cache if a key value exists but maybe I missed something.

Comment: There was an error in some earlier logic that created the NPE. However, I took your suggestion and created a custom class that implements the cache and things are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the cache is destroyed when the Activity is getting cleaned up. Check for callbacks in the library for such cleanup calls.

Comment: Wouldn't the cache persist until the activity was stopped or killed? Maybe I'm not understanding how the cache is handled by the app lifecycle

Comment: If you setup the cache in the Application class then it will never get destroyed until the app shuts down. You are guaranteed that the Application class will always be "alive" when ever one of your activities are.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem: several activities using the same cache. Two problems arise:
- the cache was never evicted...and I think the reason is the second point
- if activity B was called after activity A:
  - activity B was launched and open the cache (but Activity A does not close the cache yet !)
  - activity A close the cache in onStop() method...while B just opened it...

And my solution was to provide one cache directory per activity:

```
// retrieve the name of the activity
String nameActivity = ModelActivity.getCurrentActivity().getClass().getSimpleName();

// set the cache directory with a name related to the activity
    DiskLruImageCache imageDiskCache = new DiskLruImageCache(ModelActivity.getCurrentContext(), 
                        "cacheMediaActivity"+nameActivity, 
                        DISK_CACHE_SIZE, 
                        CompressFormat.JPEG, 
                        70);
```

And it works for me !