# Android LruCache between two activities

Tags: android

I read about using `LruCache` from developer.android.com, and I create a blurred `Bitmap` from one activity and put it into cache, now that I want to access the cached image from another activity but it returned null. Any examples or links on how to properly use cache will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Refer this ... http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Comment: Thank you for replying first. I read the exact same article but as far as I could understand it stays in the same activity through the whole process right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LruCache` is being instantiated in one class. It won't be accessible from another class. You could try the approach mentioned in this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14325075/2931650